# My code generates a path through a grid - How can I simplfy it in terms of list, dictionary's, stacks and queues?

Tags: c#, stack, pathfinding

This code works but is cluttered and I think could be improved in terms of how it is implemented.

Basically my code works - what it does is from the start location, it chooses a random direction and then moves in that direction, stores the location and repeats until there are no more directions to move. Then it works back to the last direction not moved and repeats.

I use **myarray** to store the grid to navigate and **mystack** to work through each grid location which is populated with possible move directions from each location.

I then use two dictionaries **pathFound** / **parentsList** to store the path as its found and the parent location of each step in the path.

Now I am sure there must be a better way of managing the data instead of a stack and two dictionaries.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Maze : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject myCube;

    [SerializeField] int myGridWidth = 10;
    [SerializeField] int myGridHeight = 10;
    [SerializeField] Vector2Int start;
    [SerializeField] Vector2Int end;
    int[,] myArray;

    //Array to randomise direction
    [SerializeField] Vector2Int[] Directions = { Vector2Int.up, Vector2Int.right, Vector2Int.down, Vector2Int.left };

    Stack<Vector2Int> myStack = new Stack<Vector2Int>();
    Dictionary<Vector2Int, MyPath> pathFound = new Dictionary<Vector2Int, MyPath>();
    Dictionary<Vector2Int, MyPath> parentsList = new Dictionary<Vector2Int, MyPath>();


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        myArray = new int[myGridWidth, myGridHeight];

        myStack.Push(start);
        int steps = 0;
        Vector2Int parentPos = new Vector2Int(-1, -1);
        int pathCol = 0;

        //Loop Around the Queue
        while (myStack.Count > 0 && steps<200)
        {
            var position = myStack.Pop();
            var mycube = Instantiate(myCube, new Vector3((position.x * 10)-20, 0, (position.y * 10) + 10 * 5 + 5), Quaternion.identity);

            if (parentsList.ContainsKey(position))
            {
                pathCol = parentsList[position].myColor+40;
                parentPos = parentsList[position].parent;
            }

            Color32 aColour = new Color32(0, (byte)(pathCol), 0, 255);
            mycube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = aColour;

            pathFound.Add(position,new MyPath(parentPos,pathCol));
            print("Position " + position + " Colour " + pathCol);
            moveToNeighbour(position, pathCol);
            steps++;
       
        }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<Vector2Int, MyPath> trail in pathFound)
            {
                print(trail.Key + " / " + pathFound[trail.Key].parent);
            }
        }

    private void moveToNeighbour(Vector2Int myposition, int pathColour)
    {
        //Randomise Directions
        for (int t = 0; t < Directions.Length; t++)
        {
            Vector2Int tmp = Directions[t];
            int r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(t, Directions.Length);
            Directions[t] = Directions[r];
            Directions[r] = tmp;
        }

        bool endofpath = true;
        //Check if we can go in each direction
        for (int t = 0; t < Directions.Length; t++)
        {
            var newpos = myposition + Directions[t];
            //print ("New Pos " + newpos);

            //Check its not off the grid
            if (newpos.x >= 0 && newpos.y >= 0 && newpos.x<myGridWidth && newpos.y <myGridHeight)
            {
                if (!myStack.Contains(newpos) && !pathFound.ContainsKey(newpos))
                {
                    myStack.Push(newpos);
                    parentsList.Add(newpos, new MyPath(myposition, pathColour));
                    endofpath = false;
                }
            }
        }

        //Print out end of a path found
        if (endofpath)
        {
            print("end of path found at " + myposition);
        }

    }

}
```

MyPath class is to store the position and colour of each locations parent.

```
public class MyPath
{
    public Vector2Int parent;
    public int myColor;

    public MyPath(Vector2Int position2, int thecolor)
    {
        parent = position2;
        myColor = thecolor;
    }
}
```